# Is the word problem of CFLs in NC?

Tags: algorithms, context-free, formal-grammars, parallel-computing, parsers

Consider the membership problem for a context-free language. An instance of this problem can be described as pair $(G,w)$, where $G$ is a context-free grammar and $w$ is a string.

Lets say I have a PRAM and I want it to decide in $\log^k n$ time and $n^c$ space complexity whether $w$ is in $L(G)$ ($c$ and $k$ are both constants) – that is, the complexity stays within Nick's class.

Is there such an algorithm? If so what would be an idea?

Comment: [This article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(88)90047-6) may contain helpful references and ideas.

Comment: Alright, so the exact task can be rewritten like this:

Assume MEM problem, problem which has CF grammar $G$ and word $w$ on input and asks if $w \in L(G)$. Next assume problem EMP, which has CFL G on the input and asks if there is a word $w$ s.t. $w \in L(G)$.
Proof that $MEM \leq_{NC} EMP$.

I just assumed that reduction can be done via solving the $MEM$ problem (with PRAM) and then return NON-empty / empty grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been shown that CFL ⊆ NC² ⊆ NC [1] -- so yes, there is such an algorithm. I'm afraid the proof in that paper does not give you a PRAM algorithm, though.

---

1. [On uniform circuit complexity](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-0000(81)90038-6) by W. Ruzzo (1981)

Comment: Yes I just found the same article as source from your previous response article. As you noted this proof is done via uniform boolean circuts and not via PRAM.

Comment: Is this what the question's asking for? I interpret "$\mathrm{CFL}\subseteq\mathrm{NC}^2$" as meaning "every context-free language can be decided in $\mathrm{NC}^2$" but the question seems to be asking "Is the language $\{\langle G\rangle;w\mid G \text{ is a context-free grammar that generates }w\}$ in $\mathrm{NC}$?"

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's indeed a subtly different problem, but I daresay it should not be harder.

Comment: @Raphael I have little intuition about context-free languages but it's much harder in the regular case: "Does this given NFA accept this input?" looks like it ought to be **NL**-complete (it's essentially about the existence of paths in digraphs).

Comment: @DavidRicherby as Raphael said, that is not the same problem. Unfortunately it should be done with PRAM (homework task, looks like I skip this one though). I will let you know about the solution as soon as I get it.

Comment: @user2174310 If it's homework, I guess at least one of the following two approaches will work: 1) Adapt one of the standard CFG parsing algorithms. 2) Use an algorithmic technique presented in lecture, but in another context.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in NC unless P=NC. Jones and Laaser showed in ["Complete Problems for Deterministic Polynomial Time"](https://doi.org/10.1145/800119.803883) that the problem (therein called CFMEMBER) is P-complete.
Interestingly, Ullman and Van Gelder showed in ["Parallel Complexity of of logical query programs"](https://doi.org/10.1007%2Fbf01762108) that the same problem where the input CFG has no epsilon productions is in NC (Corollary 7.2).